# Can i use " at the hands of" this way? plus,is my example grammatically correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

It's the article I posted on my Facebook.

> Taking off the lense , i always feel a tingle of something annoying. maybe i touch my eyeballs removing the lense more often than not, it actually feels like there is something like parethesia , AT THE HANDS OF bloody lense , rubing deep in my whole eyes.

Comment: As a note, the pronoun, I, should always be capitalized and there should not be a space **before** a comma. Also, "lense" does not have an "e" on the end, it's just "lens". :)

Comment: And since contact lenses do not have hands and do not act by themselves, I don't think you're justified in using "at the hands of" when talking about effects the lens has on your eye.

Comment: @VictorBazarov surely it can be used metaphorically?

Comment: Of course, jokingly.

Comment: "At the hands of" is very often used figuratively.  But it rings strange here, maybe just because anthropomorphic lenses are such a stretch.  But considering the context where the lens and fingers are the two suspects, giving the lens 'hands' is definitely inviting confusion.

Comment: *lens*, *I*, *Maybe*, *removing the lens. More*, *rubbing*. Please take care to capitalize, point and spell correctly, as far as you know how. It makes your question much easier to understand, and it will give you good practice!

Answer (score 2):

I'll give an answer here as no one else has.

First of all, there are a couple spelling issues and capitalization issues that others have pointed out.

lense->lens, 
i->I when by itself through your Facebook article, 
rubing->rubbing.  Rube is a real word and has a different meaning.

For your actual question, you need an article of some sort - probably 'the', but 'a' could work depending on what you are trying to convey.

> Taking off the lens, I always feel a tingle of something annoying. Maybe it is because I am touching my eye when removing the lens.  More often than not, it actually feels like there is something like parethesia, at the hands of the bloody lens, rubbing deep into my whole eye.

The metaphor flows a bit better, but is quite disturbing when you add bloody to it.  I don't like thinking about bleeding eyes.  Or you could just be using bloody as an expletive (British) which may fit ok, but still feels strange to my American English where you could choose one of many 'fun' words in its place.

Comment: +1 for "but is quite disturbing when you add bloody to it"  and even though I think they *are* using the BrE expletive sense here, you're right it just doesn't go well.